# Scheduled Reminder Ignoring the Year of Membership End Dates

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contribution-page, scheduled-reminders

Our site is configured to send a scheduled reminder 1 day after the membership expiration date. Memberships are renewed through a contribution page. The reminder is only sent to non-auto renew members. When a member renews their membership it updates the expiration date to the following year but the reminders are still being sent.

For example, A member's membership end date was October 14th, 2019. She renewed her membership on September 24th, 2019 which changed her membership end date to October 14th, 2020 but she still received a scheduled reminder on October 15, 2019.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? From my understanding, the scheduled reminder and contribution page is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could relate to when the Job for Update Membership Status runs compared to when the Job for Send Scheduled Reminders run.

Eg if the above are both set for daily then it is possible that the Update Memb Status runs after the Send Scheduled Reminders, and then the Reminder is created/sent before the Memb Status has been updated.